# Orbit in rotated ellipse path

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I am trying to make planet orbit in a rotated ellipse fashion. Inside [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1plmunayfw) desmos graph is the rotated ellipse. How do I have a point orbit along that path?

I have used $(r \sin ( \frac{1}{p} 2 \pi t)+h,r \cos ( \frac{1}{p} 2 \pi t)+k)$ to make ordinary planets orbit in a circle, but can't figure out how how to apply this to a rotated ellipse. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should the motion be realistic (i.e. obeying the gravity law) or arbitrary (as in your example)?

Comment: It is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$  be the major and minor axes of the ellipse, respectively, and $\alpha$ be the "declination" (rotation angle) of the ellipse.

The parametric equation of the ellipse centered at the origin of coordinates with the main axes directed along the coordinate axes reads:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\omega t\\ b\sin\omega t\end{pmatrix}.
$$

In the coordinate system rotated at angle $\alpha$ about the origin it will read:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\ \sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}a\cos\alpha\cos\omega t-b\sin\alpha\sin\omega t\\
a\sin\alpha\cos\omega t+b\cos\alpha\sin\omega t\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Further modifications such as shift of the coordinate origin or time are obvious and are left to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Pardon my ignorance, but how would I put this in demos?

Comment: What prevents you from doing this in the same way as in the circle case?